# Disable file input on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've got a form with text and file inputs that submits an ajax request. I want to temporarily disable the inputs while sending the request, and enable them again after to allow another submit.

For text inputs this works as expected:

```
$("form input").attr('readonly','readonly');
```

However, the file input still allows the user to select a new file (open the dialog). Setting the "disabled" property stops this but then the file is not submitted with the form.

- Is this expected behavior for "readonly"?
- Is there another solution to this?
- Or does it really matter if the file changes after submit?

Comment: I don't think it matters if the file changes after submit. The original value is what gets sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use a call back data in your server side when the request is successfully sent
then use this to get the call back.

`$.post("YourUrl",{request: "Your Request"})
.done
(function(data){\your code here});`

Comment: disable it when clicked.. then enable it when the a .done data is true